# How to force uitableview to resize a cell (after deactivating a height constraint)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to put an extendable `UITableViewCell` by tapping on a button.

I am using the constraints to force the dynamic `UITextView` to tell the `UITableViewCell` the its new height. (using autolayout and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`)

This works as expected without the button: The height of the `UITableViewCell` depends on the `UITextView`'s height.

Having a constraint on the `UITextView` to maximize the size of the cell, when tapping the button (the cell is collapsed), I want to remove height constraint to the `UITextView` (that is limiting the cell height) and update the cell accordingly. Here's the extend method:

```
-(void)extendCellWasTapped:(UITableViewCell*)senderCell{

    MAFollowingPostTableViewCell *cell = (MAFollowingPostTableViewCell*)senderCell;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (![self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    if ([self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath] ) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[cell.constraintTextViewHeight]];

           // CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];

// I would like to minimize the animations as well here.. but thats another //problem
//            [self.tableView.layer removeAllAnimations];
//            [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
//            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

        });
    }
}
```

If I tap the button and then scroll to a similar cell, it is already expanded. So I am missing something here. I already tried to do `[cell updateConstraints]` after deactivating the constraint, but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

At first, the button doesn't show up for some reason. And I noticed that (with the same code) if I scroll down and then up, the button shows up and, if I try to extend it, it works.

**UPDATE**

This is my UIViewController :

http://www.gfycat.com/FairBossyAfricanporcupine

Notice that the extend button is not there, but once I scroll down/up it comes shows up and it extends the cell once I tap on the extend button.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when the textSize is being calculated (to see if the cell is extendable or not), at first, the textView is wider than its final state. And I am performing this check on the cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MAPostTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.delegate = self;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

MAPostFollowing *post = (MAPostFollowing*)[self.arrayPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

cell.textViewTitle.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

NSString *title = [post.post title];

[cell.textViewTitle setText:title];

UIButton * buttonExtend = [cell buttonExtend];

if ([self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.constraintTextViewHeight.active = NO;

    if (![buttonExtend isHidden]) {
        buttonExtend.hidden = YES;
        buttonExtend.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}else{

    cell.constraintTextViewHeight.active = YES;

    NSLog(@"index %li", (long)indexPath.row);

    BOOL b = ![self isTitleExtendable:title forTextView:cell.textViewTitle]; // Checks if the current text view is able to fit the title. If not, it will show the buttonExtend

    buttonExtend.hidden = b;
    buttonExtend.userInteractionEnabled = !b;

}
}
...
```

So on the first run (before scrolling) the [self isTitleExtendable:title forTextView:cell.textViewTitle]; does not return the desired value as the textView doesn't have the right width when the textSize is being calculated.

So I believe have the following options : 
- force the textViewTitle to refresh after it has changed the layout (thus calculating correctly the extendable UI state)
- recheck the extendable UI state once the textViewTitle changes the width

**UPDATE**

On the method prepareForReuse the textViewTitle still has a wider frame. On the layoutSubviews method it has in fact a small frame. The challenge here is that is gets called more often, and it gets me false cases (button being shown when it shouldn't)

This is what I was experimenting with :

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
[super layoutSubviews];

BOOL b = [self isTitleExtendable:self.textViewTitle.text forTextView:self.textViewTitle];

self.buttonExtend.hidden = !b;
self.buttonExtend.userInteractionEnabled = b;

if (!b) {
    NSLog(@"Button hidden YES UserInteraction NO");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Button hidden NO UserInteraction YES");
}

NSLog(@"textViewTitle layout %f",self.textViewTitle.frame.size.width);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to remove the constraints instead of deactivate it `[cell removeConstraints:cell.constraintTextViewHeight]` ?

Comment: same thing. Not sure if it'll work once the cell gets reused (that's why I am deactivating instead of removing)

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what the question is.  By looking at your GIF it sounds like the issue is that the button is not there when the cell is first rendered.  In the question you seem to imply, instead that the button is there and does not work.  Bear with me, perhaps it is just me misinterpreting the question.

Comment: you are right. The button is not there in the first place, so the behavior that I desire does not work for those.

Comment: Did you already try to [tableView reloadData] and [view setNeedsDisplay] for the views/buttons/controls?

Comment: The problem is really hard to track if you can't see the constraints, priority and your configuration. Do you set any stuff that is related with the button under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Because without doing anything just dequeuing the cell again should not have any problem. Also how do you dequeue it (I mean do you dequeue with indexPath)?

Comment: @kvr check my update

Answer (score 5):

To do such a thing, you shouldn't rely on constraint, but on `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` you just have to give the right height depending on the context.

Pushing your button would trigger a change so `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` returns a different value for your cell that you extend.

And just after doing this trigger, just do:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

without anything between them, it will trigger the "natural animation" of `UITableView` and do exactly what you want

Comment: as the description says, I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: I would still go for the begin-end update trick to force animation update ;) But I didn't try when using auto-sized cells

Answer (score 0):

Are forgetting to **remove indexpath** from **self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths** ?

```
if (![self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}
else
{
   [self.arrayExtendedTitlesAtIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: No. This is the action that is taken once a user taps on an extend button. And once he does, that cell will always be extended.

Answer (score 0):

If the button isn't there and while you scrolling it show again surely you have a problem with reusability.

You're probably decide about to show or hide button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If you have a condition there try to show this button always, and if this will work as expected then hide a button inside a cell whenever this constraint is there or not. The right method is `prepareForReuse` inside `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: This might be the way to go. I am still not 100% sure about the implementation though

Answer (score 0):

Call `[cell layoutSubviews];` once your changes are completed.

Comment: Per the documentation on the layoutSubviews: method: "You should not call this method directly."